# rnorm vs numpy.random.randn

Tags: r, regression, python, random-generation, numpy

For a regression example, I constructed some artificial data and ran ols,

```
import pandas as pd
n = 100
df = pd.DataFrame()
np.random.seed(1)
df['x1'] = np.random.randn(n)
df['x2'] = np.random.randn(n)
df['x3'] = np.random.randn(n)
df['x4'] = np.random.randn(n)
df['y'] = 10 + -100*df['x1'] +  75*df['x3'] + np.random.randn(n)
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
results = smf.ols('y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 ', data=df).fit()
print results.summary()
```

The result

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       1.000
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  1.000
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                 3.397e+05
Date:                Fri, 13 Mar 2015   Prob (F-statistic):          2.00e-196
Time:                        16:04:29   Log-Likelihood:                -140.87
No. Observations:                 100   AIC:                             291.7
Df Residuals:                      95   BIC:                             304.8
Df Model:                           4                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept     10.0787      0.103     97.783      0.000         9.874    10.283
x1          -100.0711      0.116   -864.165      0.000      -100.301   -99.841
x2            -0.1041      0.112     -0.931      0.354        -0.326     0.118
x3            75.0392      0.103    726.037      0.000        74.834    75.244
x4            -0.2711      0.096     -2.824      0.006        -0.462    -0.080
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        1.621   Durbin-Watson:                   1.709
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.445   Jarque-Bera (JB):                1.283
Skew:                          -0.050   Prob(JB):                        0.526
Kurtosis:                       2.454   Cond. No.                         1.38
==============================================================================
```

The result suggests the 4th variable is significant when in fact, it is not (artificial y did not include it).

But when I use R to generate artificial data the same way

```
set.seed(1)
n = 100
x1 = rnorm(n)
x2 = rnorm(n)
x3 = rnorm(n)
x4 = rnorm(n)
y = 10 -100*x1 + 75*x3 +  rnorm(n)
dat = data.frame(cbind(x1,x2,x3,x4,y))
write.csv(dat, '/tmp/out.csv')
```

and load this data, run ols()

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
df = pd.read_csv('/tmp/out.csv')
results = smf.ols('y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 ', data=df).fit()
print results.summary()
```

I get

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       1.000
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  1.000
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                 2.502e+05
Date:                Fri, 13 Mar 2015   Prob (F-statistic):          4.03e-190
Time:                        16:07:36   Log-Likelihood:                -154.89
No. Observations:                 100   AIC:                             319.8
Df Residuals:                      95   BIC:                             332.8
Df Model:                           4                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept      9.9430      0.118     84.263      0.000         9.709    10.177
x1           -99.8067      0.131   -762.203      0.000      -100.067   -99.547
x2             0.1696      0.123      1.380      0.171        -0.074     0.414
x3            75.0337      0.114    655.983      0.000        74.807    75.261
x4             0.0427      0.119      0.357      0.722        -0.195     0.280
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        2.555   Durbin-Watson:                   1.988
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.279   Jarque-Bera (JB):                2.051
Skew:                           0.339   Prob(JB):                        0.359
Kurtosis:                       3.180   Cond. No.                         1.26
==============================================================================
```

Now x2 and x4 are not significant, as they should (not) be. What I am curious about is what is np.random.randn doing that is so different from R's random numbers? I tried scipy.stats.norm.rvs, also numpy.random.normal, the result is the same (bad x4).

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: What happens when you re-run these analyses with different seeds?

Comment: Intresting. seed(10) worked, now on Python side x2 and x4 are not significant, which is right.

Comment: It is the nature of statistical conclusions that they are uncertain and subject to random variation!

Comment: Can you include less uncertainty and random variation in your explanation?

Comment: @user423805 try running each simulation several times in both languages. Say, run it 30 times at n = 100, and 30 times at n = 1000. And keep in mind that p values are themselves random variables